# How to use csrf in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3 i want to use csrf in my project when i true csrf_protection it show an error like (the action you have requested is not allowed.) when i do false of csrf_protection the value is empty when i make it ture then the this error shows(the action you have requested is not allowed.) how can i use csrf thanks in advance.
config.php

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

in my view i am using this

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
```

Comment: Just use the `form_open()` function, it will create the form and the hidden input for you

Comment: Read this document: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Comment: nothing word use this form_open() when use $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; than show an error when it FALSE teken value is empty

Answer (score 0):

set `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` in `application/config.php`

Comment: @shahid Would you mind posting the error so we can help?